# Can Bootstrap stack 1st and third column beside 2nd on desktop?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a layout I'm trying to create that is pretty simple on mobile:

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
```

But on desktop, I'm trying to make [B] become larger and move off to the right side, while A and C stack on the left.

```
[ A ][ B ]
[ C ][ B ]
```

Can Bootstrap 4 do this, or do I need to write my own grid css?

Update: here's aexample with the basic layout I have right now:

```css
.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: blue; }
.c { background-color: green; }
img {max-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="a col-md-5">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="b col-md-7">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Example_image.svg" alt="B (should be right of A and C on desktop)" />
    </div>
    <div class="c col-md-5">
      <p>C (should be below A and left of B on desktop)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/nfriedly/pen/rqMLBw

Update 2: here's some images to clarify things. ([A] is red, [B] is blue (with an image), [C] is green.)

Current layout:

[image: actual]

Desired layout:

[image: expected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, it seem that the answer is "no, Bootstrap's flexbox-based layout can't do that".

As [JoostS showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674017/933879), the layout can be done with `position`'ing and `!important`, but that's not exactly *bootstrap* doing it. It's more like bootstrap being beaten into submission while fighting me all the way down.

So, I think I'm going to drop bootstrap's grid entirely and switch to something using `display: grid`:

```css
.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: blue; }
.c { background-color: green; }
img {max-width: 100%; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: grid;
  }
  .b {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="a">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Example_image.svg" alt="B (should be right of A and C on desktop)" />
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p>C (should be below A and left of B on desktop)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/nfriedly/pen/bmweKB?editors=1100

This gets me the behavior I want without feeling like I'm resorting to hacks and fighting my tools. It [may not work in legacy browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid), but that's acceptable for my use-case.

Comment: I like this solution. I laughed about 'fighting me al the way down', because I proposed only two lines of CSS in a single media query, but I have to admit that it is not the Bootstrap way.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was being *a bit* dramatic ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can make [B] absolute on desktop and let it stick to the right side of the container. Use this CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {position: relative;}
  .b {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;}
}
```

Note that the `600px` should be equal to your desktop break-point.

Here is a [working version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wYzWWa).

Comment: I tried that, but [C] ends up on top of [B]. I put it [C] it's own .row, which solved that, but something funky is going on with [B]'s width and position, it seems to be the width of the entire .container and too far over to the right despite the right: 0.

Comment: I also added actual and expected images to the question to clarify it.

Comment: I see, that does work. I was hoping to avoid absolute positioning (and !important's), but this will do if I can't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using Bootstrap 4, you can order the row column as you desire using the 'order' property .
For example if you want the C column come before the B column you can simply do this :

```
C{ order : 1; }
B{ order : 2;}
```

And the A column has already the order : 0 .

Comment: That doesn't seem to have the desired effect, unless I'm misunderstanding you. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/nfriedly/pen/dgpXPg

Comment: I also added actual and expected images to the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout ordering classes found in bootstrap’s [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) (jump to reordering).

You can also use it with their screen sizing options so that it’ll only follow that order when the page is viewed on a given screen size. This can be done by adding xs, sm, md or lg.

```
<div class=“col-sm-3 order-md-3”>
    <p> sample </p>
 </div>
```

Here's a [`working example`](https://jsfiddle.net/RaysOfTheSun/aq9Laaew/244249/)

On the other hand, the column widths can also be expanded like [`this`](https://jsfiddle.net/RaysOfTheSun/aq9Laaew/244271/).

If this does not solve your problem. I at least hope it'll give you an idea on how to go about it using only bootstrap :)

Comment: I'm not sure quite how to use that to get the desired output. I updated the question with a code sample and a pair of images for current and desired layout.

Comment: Hi @NathanFriedly I've added a working example to my answer :)